# How to properly wire fuse block, DC-DC converter, and load

Tags: batteries, dc-dc-converter, safety, wiring, short-circuit

I have a battery, a fuse block, and three PCs (Raspberry Pi.)

Is it better to have three separate DC-DC converters in front of the fuse block with the battery directly connected to the fuse block or have one large DC-DC converter in front of the battery going into the fuse block? I think by 'better' I mean if something were to short or draw too much current.

I have attached a picture below of the two scenarios:

[image]

Comment: Do the RPi's have any interconnections between then other than (isolated Ethernet)? Regardless of if you go with one or three converters, please place a fuse directly after the battery in case the boost converter goes short circuit.

Comment: They will be connected only by an ethernet switch. That's a good point about putting a fuse regardless after the battery in case the converter goes short. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do want to have a fuse as close as possible to the battery, to protect against as many short circuits as possible. If you had no fuse between the battery and the converter, you wouldn't be as protected against short circuits in the converter.

You also shouldn't need 3 separate converters. Even if you want to fuse each Pi separately (and why not? the more fuses the better) you can put three 5A fuses after the single converter, one going to each Pi.

If your "fuse block" is wired in a way that connects all the fuses together in one side, so you can't use it for both purposes at the same time, then you might have to modify it or find a different arrangement to hold your fuses.